# Applying '>' in if condition with a vector larger than length 1 in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of size 5 e.g.:

```
 a<-c(1,4,6,3,2)
```

I also have another vector of size 1:

```
 b<-9
```

I would like to write the following if condition:

```
if (a>b) { 1
}
else 0
}
```

I get the following warning:

```
 Warning message:
In if (fitness_neighbours > user_fitness) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What I would actually like it to do is to check if any of the elements in 'a' satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `any()` and a comparison:

```
if(any(a > b)) {
  # Executes if any value in a > b.
} else {
  # No a is greater than b.
}
```

Another way of doing it using `pmax()`:

```
if (any(pmax(a, b) == a)) {

} else {

}
```

That's saying that if any of the max of (`a`, `b`) is equal to the value in `a`, then `a` must be greater.

Answer (score 3):

Just use simple comparison:

```
a <- c(1,4,6,3,20)
b <- 9
a > b

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

This works because R is fundamentally a vector-based language.

You can easily convert the logical result to numeric:

```
as.numeric(a > b)
[1] 0 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is whether any of the values satisfy the condition:

```
any(a>b)  # no need for `if`
```

If that needs to be 1/0 then either of these would work:

```
as.numeric( any(a>b) )
c(0,1)[1+any(a>b)] # because indexing has origin at 1 rather than 0-based indexing
```

If the goal were to pick which ones satisfied, use logical indexing

```
a[ a>b ]
```

And if you wanted to choose between which of two elements from 2 other vectors to chose in a "parallel" fashion, based on an element by element decision, then use `ifelse` rather than `if (){ }else{ }`

```
ifelse( a>b, 1:5, seq(2,10, by=2) )
# returns 2 4 6 8 10
```